# How to solve recurrences related to factorials?

Tags: recurrence-relations, computer-science, closed-form

I have come across recurrences like $T(n) = n + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{T(i-1)}$ . All I could make out is that they are related to factorials and binomial coefficients and expanding them doesn't seem to lead me anywhere. Also, a reduction for the purpose of finding an asymptotic upper bound to $T(n)$.. like $T(n) \leq n+(n-1)T(n-1)$ don't seem to give a closed form solution.

Is there a way to solve the recurrence in its original or reduced form ? Or any general method for obtaining closed form solutions to these factorial-like recurrences like master theorem etc.?

Comment: The particular recurrence equation you've mentioned is in fact directly solvable noting that $ T ( n + 1 ) - T ( n ) = 1 + T ( n - 1 ) $. There are similar recurrences where you can eliminate the complex part of the recurrence by comparison between specific terms of the sequence, and coming up with simpler recurrences that can be solved easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can easily get
$$T(n+1)=T(n)+T(n-1)+1.$$
If $T(0)=T(1)=1$, we call $\{T(n)\}$ the *Leonardo sequence*. Now we claim that

> Let $F_n$ be the $n$th *Fibonacci number*. Then
>   $$T(n)=2F_{n+1}-1.\tag{1}$$

**PROOF.** For $n=0$ and $n=1$, (1) is easily verified.

Now suppose that (1) is true for $0\leqslant k\leqslant n$. Thus
\begin{align*}
T(n+1)& =T(n)+T(n-1)+1\\
& =(2F_{n+1}-1)+(2F_n-1)+1\\
& =2(F_{n+1}+F_n)-1\\
& =2F_{n+2}-1.
\end{align*}
Hence (1) holds for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.$\quad\square$

If $T(0)=2a-1,T(1)=2b-1$, (1) is also true, but now $F_n$ satisfies that
$$F_1=a,\ F_2=b,\ F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n.$$
I'm sure that it's enough.